# AppFabric WCF Monitoring/logging not working

Tags: wcf, appfabric

Have setup AppFabric, linked to event logging sql db etc. Wcf service working fine but not recording ANY logs of successful/failed calls - all dashboard counts are zero. No errors in Event Viewer of the server.

Have read all I can find and double-checked all settings - no luck.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

By default your application will inherit monitoring settings from the root web.config file. I'd first check your applications web.config to see if you've accidentally turned monitoring off for it. If all looks good there, try running AppFabric configuration tool just to make sure everything is configured properly.